# $q promise not resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I can't figure out why this isn't resolving, any ideas? "resolve this" does print, but it never makes it back to the resolution of the promise in .then.

```
var promise = wait(); 
promise.then(function(result){
    console.log("wait returned - " + result); 
}); 

function wait(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(busy){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            wait(); 
        },500); 
    } else {
        console.log("resolve this");
        deferred.resolve("Wait is over."); 
    }
return deferred.promise; 
};
```

Comment: What changes `busy`? Anyway, you always create a new deferred object with each subsequent `wait` call - but return only the one from the first call, apparently.

Comment: you return different promises every time you call `wait`

Comment: Busy is just a flag set somewhere else. I didn't think about it creating that promise every call...duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be done instead:

```
var promise = wait(); 
promise.then(function(result){
    console.log("wait returned - " + result); 
}); 

function wait(){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  (function _wait() {
    if (busy) { 
      setTimeout(_wait, 500);
    } else {
      console.log("resolve this");
      deferred.resolve("Wait is over."); 
    }
  })();
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

The key difference is that there will be only one `deferred`, created and returned by a 'wrapper' function. This deferred will be eventually resolved by `_wait` function.

In your case, each subsequent (recursive) `wait()` call creates a different `deferred` object. One of these objects will be eventually resolved, right - but that will be the same object as returned by the first `wait()` call only if `busy` will be false at this moment. Apparently, most of the time it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call wait, it makes a *new* promise. The calls to `wait` inside your `setTimeout` function do nothing to the first promise created. Try this instead:

```
var promise = wait(); 
promise.then(function(result){
    console.log("wait returned - " + result); 
}); 

function wait(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(!busy) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log("resolve this");
            deferred.resolve("Wait is over."); 
        }
    }, 500);
    return deferred.promise; 
};
```

Also, depending on how the rest of your program is structured, it may be a good idea to resolve the promise *as soon as* `busy` becomes `true`; then you don't have to wait as long.