# How do I (really!) make JavaScript async call sync (on Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, ecmascript-6, traceur

I am aware somewhat similar questions have been asked a gazillon times, but I really need to make an async call truly synchronous. I generally have to use AMD in an async fashion and I have to make sure some calls to `require` execute synchronously - after the passed in callback has executed. It would be enough to make it work on chrome. Seems the trick can be done with ES6 `yield`/`await`. Unfortunately, `yield` seems to require `traceur` with chrome. In fact, I would like to have a lightweight, bare minimum solution and avoid introducing a big library footprint.

What's the bare minimum solution to get this implemented?

Comment: Is there any state (=visible to the require calls' scope) variable that can be set by the callback?

Comment: Yes. I could do: "var whatEverIWantSetFromCallBack;require(...);// onlyProceedWhenSetByCallBack;"

Comment: Then you can delay the `require` call, like shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26409908/1229023), right? You'll need to check that var instead of `busy`, and execute the callback (supplied into `wait`) instead of resolving the promise, but the main idea will be the same.

Comment: `yield`/`await` doesn't make asynchronous calls synchronous. It just re-writes your method so that you don't have to do the callbacks yourself.

Comment: Isn't `await` ES7? Either way, it's supported by regenerator: https://facebook.github.io/regenerator/.

Comment: I may be missing something in your suggestion raina77ow, but I don't see how this helps. I have to make sure execution does not pass the a synchronous replacement for require. There is 3rd-party code relying on the fact that the callback has kicked in. I know this might sound strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it.  JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded and asynchronous.  Do you really want your JavaScript blocking your UI thread as you wait for a file to load from the server?

I've never seen a situation where you need synchronous code in JS.  Can you give us an example of why you feel like synchronous code is necessary?

As far as `yield`/`await`, you can make your code look like it is synchronous, but it is really a "coroutine" which means that the function has multiple entry points.  In other words, it is still asynchronous.  ES6 is getting generators and the `yield` keyword, but `await` is in the ES7 spec.  Don't hold your breath for it.

You can use <strike>[Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler)</strike> [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) or [Regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator) to transpile your code to support generators and `yield`, which is really nice.  You can then use [co](https://github.com/tj/co) to turn your generator function into a coroutine.  I have an [example of this working in chrome](http://learnharmony.org/#es6discuss/coroutines) at [LearnHarmony](http://learnharmony.org).

You can also use the `import`/`export` keywords in ES6 (using traceur or some other transpiler/polyfill) to get what looks like synchronous code: `import Foo from 'foo'`.  But don't let it fool you.  It is also asynchronous.  The Traceur compiler will transpile that code into async code.

Comment: The code in question is at https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/slingshot/source/web/js/alfresco/core/CoreWidgetProcessing.js#L429 . Comments above the call explain the situation. The widgets build a tree and fire events when their children are initialized. In fact, the events must not fire before the child-tree is fully initialized. Keeping track async gets convoluted quickly and I don't want to patch files all over the framework. Disabling the aggregation and using AMD in sync mode works but you loose source file information in the browser.

Comment: Can you not use promises and do something like `Promise.all`?  Whatever the case, truly synchronous code is not possible.  You need to architect around it.  Promises help.  And so do coroutines/yield, which you can use in modern browsers if you transpile/polyfill.

Comment: By the way yield/await is schedules to ship in Chrome 55 around Dec 6, 2016.

Comment: Indeed, browsers are starting to support it and `yield/await` is available using Babel today. Back when I wrote this, Traceur was the bomb.  Today, it is Babel.